# hive table shows null output while display the data

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

Hive showing null

```
create table users (name string, id int) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;



Output received
raj   NULL
venkat NULL
appu   NULL
sony   NULL
lg     NULL
nani   NULL
```

Can I know what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like you need to provide some more context - like what was the query you ran to retrieve the data?

Comment: load data local inpath '/home/cloudera/a/users.txt' into table users;

Answer (score 0):

Can u share sample data lines ?? It is most likely because the records are not tab delimited. Create a new file of few records and make sure it's not space but tab delimited and try again..

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be any one of these or all:

1.) Your data file does not have value for second column.

2.) Your data file has two columns but the second column is not an integer.

Hope it helps...!!!